# To find the value of c and to find the PDF of mixed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

I don't know how to find the PDF of mixed random variable. Please help me here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** This is a continuous cdf where $P(X\leq 3)=P(X>3)$. Thus

$$F(3)=\frac{c(6\cdot3 -3^2-1 )}{2}=P(X\leq 3)=P(X>3)=1$$

Solve the equation for $c$.

Comment: I got the answer but still I want to know how to find the PDF of that given CDF

Comment: Just differentiate the function for the corresponding intervals.

Comment: But when you will try to find the CDF from the PDF.... then I don't think it will be same..... and one more thing how can you consider P(X<=3)=P(X>3)?

Comment: "But when you will try to find the CDF from the PDF.... then I don't think it will be same."  Don´t forget the integration constant. " and one more thing how can you consider $P(X\leq 3)=P(X>3)$? Because $f(x)=0$ for $x>3$. That mean that $F(3)$ must be 1. It cannot be less.